# simple android Snackbar not working

Tags: android, button, android-activity, layout, snackbar

I was trying to show a very simple Snackbar in the MainActivity in my app, after clicking on a button. This button also leads to the start of a new activity. But after I clicked it, no Snackbar show and the new Activity started. My MainActivity is a RelativeLayout and I don't quite want to change it into CoordinatorLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReceived"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Messages Received"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#3079ab"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvReceived"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/receivedList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Message"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearMain"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code of the Snackbar:

```
Button btnNewSms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newMessage);
btnNewSms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(v, R.string.new_message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
      mySnackbar.show();
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ComposeActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
     }
});
```

What is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comment your intent and run the code, the activity is starting when the button is clicked and you are not able to see the snackbar. Try and let me know if it worked

Comment: Nothing's wrong. You just can't see the `Snackbar` in the first `Activity` when the second one starts. The `startActivity()` call isn't going to wait on your `Snackbar`, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: Ah...yes it worked! Can I make the new activity start after the show up of the Snackbar? Is CoordinatorLayout require to do this?

Comment: You can put a delay between the two ops(not recommended). Use toast instead. Snackbars are seemingly intended as replacements for toasts in Android. However, toasts are not dependent on Activities, they only need a Context, meaning that they can be used from services as well, unlike Snackbars.

Comment: @Emile Check my answer, you can show the SnackBar for infinite time with a button and on the click of the button you can open your activity with an Intent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment your intent and run the code, the `Activity` is starting when the button is clicked and you are not able to see the `Snackbar`. 
You can open the `Activity` on the click of your button inside your `Snackbar` by following

```
 public void showMsgSnack(String msg) {

        snackbar = Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(), "Your Message here", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Open", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Your Intent here
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();
    }
```

Try and let me know if it worked